# How to increase the size of a select box, in Tinymce?

Tags: css, tinymce

I just wrote a tinymce plugin, which has a drop down box.  I can increase the size of the select box, by manipulating the CSS file of the advanced theme (the theme I am using).  Is there any other way to do it, without changing the CSS?  Say in the function of the javascript code that actually creates the select box?

Edit:
I did set the max_width property while creating the listbox, in the createListBox function.  But it only changes the width of the elements in the dropdown, not the drop down itself :(

Answer (score 0):

You can always change the css using javascript:

```
document.getElementById("ATTRIBUTE_ID").style.width = "1000px";
```

See this SOF link for more details: [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a closer look at the tinymce configuration option [editor_css](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aeditor_css).
Using this setting you may configure a css file which will overwrite the default css for the toolbar stuff. This way you don't need to change anything of the core css.

Answer (score 0):

tinymce dropdown generates internally and it's hard to do this in right way, but you always can access the needed element by CSS like:

```
div[id*='mceu_'].mce-container.mce-panel.mce-floatpanel.mce-menu.mce-animate.mce-fixed.mce-menu-align.mce-in div.mce-container-body.mce-stack-layout {
  max-height: 200px !important;
}
```

for me it works for all dropdown select lists inside modal windows like link-plugin - reduce height of select list block.